# Foreground and few other styles changing when Flyout displayed at the second time

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I got stuck with a strange behavior. While I show native `Flyout` at the second time, foreground style and some other styles changing for the whole app. After some searching I found the same problem in [this MSDN topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/c77ea781-6a55-4d4c-828c-0b4e440da32f/foreground-changing-when-menuflyout-displayed), but topic is locked without any solution or answer. The sample and screenshots is the same for my my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. I had `Flyout` directly in `ListView` and it cause such problems:

```
<ListView ...>
 <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
 ...
 </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</ListView>
```

After moving Flyout to the ItemTemplate, the problem is gone:

```
<ListView ...>
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <Grid ...>
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
      ...
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
   </Grid>
  <DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```